# Converting cURL code to c# izooto api

Tags: c#, api, curl

I am trying to access an api for push notifications.

This is the cURL code:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Authentication-Token: {API_TOKEN}" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
    "title" : "{NOTIFICATION_TITLE}",
    "message" : "{NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE}",
    "icon_url" : "{ICON_URL}",
    "banner_url" : "{BANNER_URL}",
    "landing_url" : "{LANDING_URL}",
    "actions" : [
       {
         "text" : "{BUTTON1_TEXT}",
         "url" : "{BUTTON1_URL}"
       },
       {
         "text" : "{BUTTON2_TEXT}",
         "url" : "{BUTTON2_URL}"
       }],
    "utm_source" : "{UTM_SOURCE}",
    "utm_medium" : "{UTM_MEDIUM}",
    "utm_campaign" : "{UTM_CAMPAIGN}",
    "ttl" : {TTL_SECONDS},
    "target" : {
            "type" : "all"
    }
  }' "https://apis.izooto.com/v1/notifications"
```

I tried to access the api through c#.

C# Code:

```
public string get()
    {
        try
        {
            WebRequest tRequest;
            tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://apis.izooto.com/v1/notifications");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
            tRequest.Headers.Add("Authentication-Token", "xxxxxxxxx-yyyyyyyyy");

            string imgurl = "https://cdnimg.izooto.com/9338/9883/93381513921358.png";
            string landing_url = "http://www.maalaimalar.com/News/TopNews/2017/12/27110835/1136906/MK-Stalin-Slams-his-Brother-MK-Stalin-for-RK-Nagar.vpf";
            string postData = "title=test&message=testmsg&icon_url=" + imgurl + "&landing_url=" + landing_url + "";

            Console.WriteLine(postData);

            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();

            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

            dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

            //lblStat.Text = sResponseFromServer;
            tReader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            tResponse.Close();
            return sResponseFromServer;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error when reaches `WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();`

Error: `System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.`

Response : `{"success":false,"message":"Authentication token missing"}`

I referred the following documentation for the curl code
https://docs.izooto.com/docs/push-to-all
Can anyone provide the solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks to me like it wants JSON but you are sending form data.

Comment: I also tried with "application/json" too

Comment: You can't just change the content type header, you also have to give the POST Body valid JSON.

Comment: Can you check the above code where i have given the required parameters.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you don't really know how HTTP works? It would help if you took the time to understand what the curl request is doing. Can you capture network trace with something like Fiddler? You can compare the two requests and see how they are different. In the c# example you are posting key/value pairs but in curl you are posting JSON, if you don't know what I mean then google about JSON and form url encoding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162037/discussion-between-chozha-rajan-and-crowcoder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass target in postData.Like below,

```
string postData= "{\n    \"title\" : \""+ title + "\",\n    \"message\" : \""+ message + "\",\n    \"icon_url\" : \""+ icon_url + "\",\n    \"banner_url\" : \"" + bannerUrl + "\",\n    \"landing_url\" : \"" + landing_url + "\",\n    \"target\" : {\n            \"type\" : \"all\"\n    }\n  }";
```